# ODOO HR Applicant Kanban View Create Stage Column with job specific

Tags: module, odoo, odoo-14

I'm working on the HR Recruiter module, Here I'm creating a stage column inside the specific job position, but the stage column is displayed in all other job positions also, but we can choose the job-specific by editing the stage. Here I want to save the job position along with stage creation, by default it should take the current job position when I am creating the stage.
[image]

Can you please help me to achieve this via code? it will very help full for me,  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something like this,

took current active_id (job position id) from the context

```
class StageInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.recruitment.stage'

    @api.model
    def create(self, vals_list):
        stage = super(StageInherit, self).create(vals_list)
        current_job_id = self._context.get('active_id')
        stage.write({'job_ids': [(4, current_job_id)]})
        return stage
```

So it creats a stage column along with job_ids